Hibernate session.merge() an object graph, but ID of an inserted object does not get returned
I have an object tree where in this particular case, the parent object exists, and a one to many set of children has one child already. Then the user adds another child and updates the parent. In code, I am functionally calling session.merge(parent).
I see the sql log show that the insert is performed on the child, the update is performed on the parent. But when I do session.flush() afterward, I'm under the impression that it should fill the inserted object with it's DB generated identifier.  It did it in the pure insert situation when the parent was inserted. But not when the parent is being updated.
I don't understand why hibernate is not populating that identifier.
Update: I've noticed in the SQL logging that in fact, it DOES query the child object's table. But hibernate does NOT put the ID into the object.
Update: Adding code. This is sort of a consolidated version. There's more than just a DB save going on here, but having walked through the debugger on this many times, this is an accurate simplified version of the hibernate things in play. The object graph is much larger and more complex than this, I'm paring it down for better communication.
The save occurs in a generic method that handles a variety of boilerplate stuff for us, but the hibernate relevant bits boil down to the below. In the past, calling flush() was enough to get hibernate to commit the record and populate IDs. But it's not in this specific condition.
Session session = getSession(); 
for(Object entity:entities) {
    session.merge(entity);
}
//checked Response object, no ID here.
session.flush(); 
//checked Response object, no ID here despite seeing both an insert AND a select involving the Response table at this point.

This is the 'Response' object, the detail to 'Review'. Note that both of these objects shown are just two among many in the object graph, I'm simplifying to the relevant fields.
@Entity
@Table(name = "RESPONSE", schema = "FR")
public class Response extends AbstractBean implements java.io.Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7839626048602639711L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "UPDT_TMSTMP", nullable = false)
    @Version
    private Date updateTimestamp;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RVW_ID", nullable = false)
    private Review review;

//and other things....
}

This is the parent object, a 'Review'. It has many children, but the most important is the 'Response'. In this situation the Review already exists, and we're inserting a Response. The ID DOES get set when inserting the first Review/Response together, or when purely updating.
@Entity
@Table(name = "REVIEW", schema = "FR")
public class Review extends AbstractBean implements java.io.Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 5572081682480208203L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "UPDT_TMSTMP", nullable = false)
    @Version
    private Date updateTimestamp;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "review", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Response> responses = new HashSet<Response>(0);

//and other things....
}

Also, before reaching that save method, other parts of the code set the association as follows, where review is an existing review queried in a prior request, and response is a new object that has been constructed and had data set to it in preparation for insertion:
    response.setReview(review);
    review.getResponses().add(response);


code kindly please.

The problem is that everything is very spread out and mixed in with other concerns.  My description is a simplification.  There's a larger object graph, and busy save methods doing various additional work.  I'll try to consolidate and put something more concise together.

@Antoniossss - Code added.  Sorry for delay.
